# Is there uniform API in C for different RDBMS'?

Tags: mysql, c, database, sqlite, libpq

I like the idea of JDBC for Java and DB-API for Python, which both provide uniform APIs for accessing different relational database management systems.

What is it like in C?

Is there uniform API in C for different RDBMS'?

I haven't found one, or I might miss it. Is such an effort successful?
POSIX doesn't seem to define a uniform API to access RDBMS'.

Thanks.

Note: I tried to read about libpq in C for postgresql, but felt the postgresql-specific API was complex, compared to JDBC and DB-API. I haven't checked the sqlite-specific or mysql-specific API yet, but expect them not similar to the one by libpq.

Comment: ODBC? Isn't that where JDBC got the name from?

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if ODBC is popular for postgresql, sqlite, and mysql under Linux,  given that ODBS was created by Microsoft,  compared to directly using RDMBS-specific drivers in Linux? If not, what is more popular?

Comment: There's libdbi but it looks dead as there hasn't been an update and barely any commits in years. I think you'll find in C on Linux/Unix people just use the native API for whatever database they're using. ODBC might get more use in the Windows world?

Answer (score 1):

In 1989, Oracle, Informix, Ingres, DEC, Tandem, Sun, and HP formed the *SQL Access Group* and defined the [Call Level Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_Level_Interface) to allow C (and COBOL) programs to access SQL databases. Nowadays, this interface specification is managed not by POSIX but by ISO/IEC (and thus part of the official SQL standard), and has also been implemented by all other SQL databases.

Microsoft's implementation of the CLI is known as "ODBC" (and has [extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/odbc-and-the-standard-cli)). And as your question shows, nobody knows the acronym "CLI", so the implementations on other OSes also call themselves "ODBC" (e.g., [unixodbc](/questions/tagged/unixodbc), [iodbc](/questions/tagged/iodbc)). Outside of Windows, they are not very widespread.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing is popular in Linux? I asked the question, because I want to learn to program to use RDBMS in C (mostly in Linux), but don't want to get lost in the DBMS-specific parts of  different APIs.